# Mod_rewrite redirect always to 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the code:

```
# No https a https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule !(cecabank)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I want to redirect to https when http is not ON and URL is not cecabank.

This works: http://sample.es/sample redirect 301 to https://sample.es/sample

This doesnt work: http://sample.es/cecabank redirect 301 to http://sample.es/index.php

I don't want redirect to index.php with 301. If I remove the HTTPS redirection works fine but It will not redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
RewriteEngine On

# No https a https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cecabank [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,END]
```

The `END` flag (available since Apache 2.4+) will take care of forced redirection.

Comment: **END** does it work but why?. `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,END]` is the last rule in the .htaccess file.

Comment: @PedroGámez Because, with `L` flag, the rules are executed once more, and since `index.php` is not an exception to the `RewriteRule` clause, the redirection occurs.